# Referencing a sass/scss variable on the fly

Tags: css, variables, sass

I am trying to get a mixin done to achieve the following.

Im having a list of social buttons. They each share the same styles except the background-color and :hover states.

My current SASS approach. (will return invalid CSS error)

```
@mixin btn-social($network) {
    .#{$network} {
        background: $#{$network}; // trying to reference a global variable

            &:hover, &:focus {
                background: darken($#{$network}, $darken-modifier); 
            }
    }
}
```

To render like this:

```
.facebook {
    background: blue; // stored in $facebook
}
.facebook:hover, .facebook:focus {
    background: darkblue; //darkend value above
}
```

I'm somehow lacking the right terms for a proper google search. I'd appreciate a push in the right direction.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a sass map to store the color variables and then find the right color using the name you pass into your mixin like so [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9y5nm5a3/2/):

```css
$colors: (
  facebook: blue,
  twitter: red
);
$darken-modifier: 100%;



@mixin btn-social($network) {
  .#{$network} {
    background: map-get($colors, $network);
    &:hover, &:focus {
      background: darken(map-get($colors, $network), $darken-modifier); 
    }
  }
}

@include btn-social(facebook);
@include btn-social(twitter);
```

```html
<a class="facebook">
  facebook
</a>

<a class="twitter">
  twitter
</a>
```

Edit: updated to include @TomOakley's suggestion below.

Comment: In OPs question, he was including the class name in the mixin, using `$network` as the class reference. This is easy to do in your example, simply wrap the mixin contents in `.#{$network} { // content }`, then you can remove `.facebook { }` and `.twitter { }` in the CSS and simply use `@include btn-social(facebook);`.

Comment: @TomOakley thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
@mixin btn-social($network, $color, $darkColor) {
    #{$network}  {
        background: $color; 

            &:hover, &:focus {
                background: $darkColor;
            }
    }
}

.foo {
  @include btn-social('.facebook', blue, darkblue)
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.foo .facebook {
  background: blue;
}
.foo .facebook:hover, .foo .facebook:focus {
  background: darkblue;
}
```

Check out **[this reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____)** for SASS interpolation.